# Unix command to validate specific path in config file

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I need to validate a file path that repeats often in a file.

All file path that begins with /usr/local must be /usr/local/test. Ignore rest of the file paths like /usr/tmp (or) /usr/logs etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should find any lines which contain strings which contain `/usr/local` which do not match `/usr/local/test`.

```
sed -n 's%/usr/local/test%%;\%/usr/local%p' filename
```

If you just want the line numbers, `=` instead of `p` does that.